# Migrating Ionic project written in Windows to MacOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have an Ionic project. I wrote and compiled it for Android on Windows. My project is running on Android. But I don't know how to compile the project on Mac. I installed XCode. I copied

> ../platform/ios

folder to Mac.

I open the project. I get the error:

`"Couldn't load project" "The file couldn't be opened"`.

How can I open the project in Xcode? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy whole project on Mac. Then add iOS platform to it, and then you can open it in Xcode.

[This guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/ios) covers how to run and debug Ionic apps on iOS simulators and devices using Capacitor or Cordova. iOS apps can only be developed on macOS with Xcode installed.

**Setting up a Development Team**

> All iOS apps must be code signed, even for development. Luckily, Xcode
> makes this easy with automatic code signing. The only prerequisite is
> an Apple ID.
>
> Open Xcode and navigate to Xcode » Preferences » Accounts. Add an
> Apple ID if none are listed. Once logged in, a Personal Team will
> appear in the team list of the Apple ID.

**Cordova Setup**

> The [ios-sim](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-sim) and [ios-deploy](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy) are utilities that deploy apps to
> the iOS simulator and iOS devices during development. They can be
> installed globally with [npm](https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/glossary#npm). This section is not necessary for Capacitor.
>
> ```
> $ npm install -g ios-sim
> $ brew install ios-deploy
> ```

Comment: Do I need to migrate the whole project? Do I need to install ionic on the Mac and compile from there? Or if I add the ios platform from windows and just move the ios folder and open it in xcode, will it work?

Comment: @Tota1907 You need to install Ionic and migrate whole project. It's easier if you have Git repository so you can pull, Android version, from there, add iOS platform, compile and after every change you can push it all to repository. For example: I primary develop on Windows, after every chage i pull changes to Mac and there i compile iOS version.